# Reading from a *.txt file in a loop

Tags: c

Is possible to read from a txt file in loop like this?
files names: input_1, input_2, ..., input_20, the "k" in "input_k" is ment as variable.

```
for ( int k=0; k<20; k++ ){
    fr = fopen("input_k", "r"){
        for ( int i=0; i<width; i++ ){
            for ( int j=0; i<height; i++ ){
                fscanf( fr, "%d", &input_k[i*width+j] );
            }  
        }
    }
    fclose(fw);
}
```

Comment: Any particular problem you're trying to solve? Anything that doesn't work for you? What are you trying to read?

Comment: That code won't even compile, so the answer is no. Also: you are leaking an epic amount of resources since you never `fclose(fr)`. Please post real code that compiles.

Comment: Please add the definition of `input_k`

Comment: You are not closing your file or check if the `fopen` fails.

Comment: also there are typos in your code "j" has not been defined.

Comment: If you are trying to read width*width integers from the file "input_k" into an array 20 times, and you replace the i's in line 4 with j's, then, yes.  Although you might want to consider closing the file each time you are done with it.  WHY you would want to read the same file into the same array 20 times is something of a mystery to me, though...

Comment: I have 20 txt files, in each is matrix 64x64 and i want to read them and don´t want to write for each one fr=fopen ... fr = fclose.

Comment: files names: input_1, input_2, ..., input_20, the "k" in "input_k" was ment as variable

Comment: Read about [`sprintf()` or `snprintf()` if you can use C99](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: Asker either have no idea whats going on or thinks we are magicians and can see rest of the code in our magic mirror. That code snippet looks badly suspicious and generally does not make sense without rest of the code.

Comment: @user1281071 - you are familiar with the problem and the code. We are not. **Please** post the code, including the definition of input_k[]. Preferably post all of the code so we could compile it. We can't help you if we can't see enough of the code to understand exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are aiming for, which will work with C89, C99, and beyond:

```
int k;
int input[20][WIDTH][HEIGHT];  // where WIDTH and HEIGHT are 
                               // compile-time constants
...
for ( k=0; k<20; k++ )
{   
  char fname[10];
  sprintf(fname, "input_%d", k);
  FILE *fr = fopen(fname, "r");
  if (fr)
  {     
    int i;    
    for (i=0; i<WIDTH; i++ )
    {  
      int j;           
      for (j=0; j<HEIGHT; j++ )
      {                 
        fscanf( fr, "%d", &input[k][i][j] );             
      }           
    }
    fclose(fr);     
  } 
}
```

However, I'm making a number of assumptions about your intentions here, so this may not be what you really want.

*EDIT*

Fixed some typos, got rid of `width` and `height` variables.

Comment: It will not work in C89 btw, C89 did not support [] for indexation of arrays, stuff like *(*(array +1)+6) had to be used (brackets could be supported by compiler though). "a[i] == *(a+i)".

Comment: @AoeAoe: What on Earth are you talking about?